# Creating Git post-receive hook to post Tag name

Tags: git, hook, git-post-receive

I have a question about ad-hoc Git configuration.

I need to pass tag name on tag post or any commit to e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    curl -X POST "https://en4c6i2k7daz5.x.pipedream.net/" \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -d '{"version": "$refname"}'            
done
```

In the result I'm getting (see https://requestbin.com/r/en4c6i2k7daz5/1cxY1mJeMlejAnF0OJ8B8iCd6sl)

```
{"version": "$refname"}
```

So for some reason it is not sending tag name (value of the `$refname`) - what is wrong in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're single-quoting your data, single-quotes exist to shut off the shell's string-construction syntax, expansions and wordsplitting and the rest. Since refnames can't have white space or glob syntax in them I think you can get by without quoting their expansionss, but for safety I usually do, to control the expansions I'll usually switch from single quotes to double quotes as needed to get that:

```
-d '{"version": "'"$refname"'"}'
```

or you could just do it all double-quotes and escape json's redundant ones to shoehorn them in that way:

```
-d "{\"version\": \"$refname\"}"
```

edit: hmmm, from `git help check-ref-format` I'm getting

> These rules make it easy for shell script based tools to parse reference names, pathname expansion by the
>          shell when a reference name is used unquoted (by mistake), and also avoid ambiguities in certain reference
>          name expressions (see gitrevisions(7)):

i.e. you' guaranteed to not  have to quote refname expansions at all.

Comment: Thanks, you've saved my day! That was so noob-style question :)